# Появление элемента только в конкретном блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, есть такая структура:

```
<div class="gallery-port">
    <figure>
        <img src="/img/portfolio/6x3.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#" class="calc-for-me btn-callback open-callback">Ссылка</a>
     </figure>
</div>

<div class="gallery-port">
    <figure>
        <img src="/img/portfolio/6x3.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#" class="calc-for-me btn-callback open-callback">Ссылка</a>
     </figure>
</div>

<div class="gallery-port">
    <figure>
        <img src="/img/portfolio/6x3.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#" class="calc-for-me btn-callback open-callback">Ссылка</a>
     </figure>
</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы при наведении на блок .gallery-port появлялась a.calc-for-me.

На данный момент есть это:

```
$('.gallery-port').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.calc-for-me').fadeIn();
});
$('.gallery-port').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.calc-for-me').fadeOut();
});
```

Но тогда, при наведении на один элемент, а.calc-for-me появляется во всех остальных, и это, в принципе, логично. Как сделать, чтобы calc-for-me появлялся именно в том блоке, на который наводишь? 
Спасибо!

Comment: Вован, ведь это можно сделать на css. Обязательно на js, ещё и через jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ищем по данному классу, но в контексте объекта, над которым совершается <strike>изуверство</strike> действо, т.е. через `this`

```js
$('.gallery-port').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('.calc-for-me').fadeIn();
});
$('.gallery-port').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.calc-for-me').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.calc-for-me {
  display:none;  
}

img {
  width: 110px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-port">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.kotomania.com/data/474.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#" class="calc-for-me btn-callback open-callback">Ссылка</a>
     </figure>
</div>

<div class="gallery-port">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.kotomania.com/data/474.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#" class="calc-for-me btn-callback open-callback">Ссылка</a>
     </figure>
</div>

<div class="gallery-port">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.kotomania.com/data/474.jpg" alt="">
        <a href="#" class="calc-for-me btn-callback open-callback">Ссылка</a>
     </figure>
</div>
```

Вместо `$(this).find('.calc-for-me')` можно использовать `$(".calc-for-me", this)`

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!!!

Comment: @vovan5150 Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).